# Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected { (1:7) , create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I started a new react project using create-react-app boilerplate (https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app), and I'm getting the following error when trying to start the app, the reason is that I have created a folder called 'containers' where all the containers go, and I want to create an index file to export all of them from that directory, this way I can just reference the directory in order to import de components.

Like this:

import UserContainer from './containers/UserContainer'; //This work(but ugly)
import { UserContainer } from './containers'; // This does not work

Basically this is the content of my index.js file inside the containers folder:

```
export UserContainer from './UserContainer';
```

And I'm getting the error Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected { (1:7),

this is the content of my package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "user-management1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "install": "^0.11.0",
    "npm": "^6.0.0",
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "react-redux": "^4.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.4",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "redux": "^3.5.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint src",
    "lint:fix": "npm run lint -- --fix",
    "lint:css": "stylelint \"src/**/*.{css,less,scss,sss}\"",
    "start": "npm run lint:fix && react-scripts start & npm run apiserver",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "apiserver": "json-server --watch --port 4000 api/db.json"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bulma": "^0.7.1",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^14.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-css-modules": "^2.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.10.3",
    "json-server": "^0.12.2"
  }
}
```

I start the app using 'react-scripts'. The problem seems related to babel?, do I need to start the app using babel-node?, or add any presets anywhere? I thought using this boilerplate babel was already configured to start coding in ES6.

Please help

Comment: can you post the file that causes the error? I mean actually the line 7

Comment: does `export { default as UserContainer } from './UserContainer';` work?

Comment: Yes, I did, it's the index.js file, and it has only one line so far, this one 'export UserContainer from './UserContainer';' is causing the problem

Comment: @Dario , that worked like a charm! Thanks, could you answer the question instead of a comment in order for me to set it up as correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically re-exporting a module (that is adding another module’s exports to those of the current module). In order to make the named export `UserContainer` of module `./UserContainer` the default export of current module you should write:

```
export { default as UserContainer } from './UserContainer'
```

Check this [link](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#sec_importing-exporting-details) for a complete reference